# Azure Applications Insights node js module not working - Fetch API cannot load error

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, reactjs, azure-application-insights

I am trying to integrate npm's application insights module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights) into my React js application.

My source for doing this is:

```
import appInsights from 'applicationinsights';
appInsights.setup(applicationInsightsKey).start();
```

The problem I got is that in my Chrome Developer tools I can see a preflight request made to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track. 
But in the console I can see the following error:

> "Fetch API cannot load https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track.
>   Request header field content-encoding is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Do you have an idea how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js module you are using is the AI SDK for Node.js server. And As the React js applications are client applications in javascript, technically they are  different.

Please try to use [ApplicationInsights-JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS).

Additionally, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/ for more info.